# Oozie job returns Error HIVETEZHS2USERACCESS

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, configuration-files, oozie

I recently reformed HDP cluster (2.6.2) on HDInsight 3.6 (previously 3.5). Since that moment my oozie Jobs defined in the old environment stopped working. What is interesting they work for shell actions, but don't work for hive actions.
There is no difference whether I run them from Oozie, or directly from HDFS.

Below workflow step that fails:

```
<action name="hive_action">
<hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
<job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
<name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.job.queuename</name>
<value>${queueName}</value>
</property>
</configuration>
<script>${CODE_DIR}/hive/sql.hql</script>
<param>WPS_DB=wh</param>
</hive>
```

I'm sure that the parameters are passed correctly. The error I'm getting is as following:

```
2018-07-04 14:34:49,721  WARN HiveActionExecutor:523 - SERVER[correct_server_name] USER[correct_user] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[categorization] JOB[correct_job_name] ACTION[correct_action@wh] Launcher exception: HIVETEZHS2USERACCESS
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HIVETEZHS2USERACCESS at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.setupSessionAcls(TezSessionState.java:233)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.open(TezSessionState.java:188)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.open(TezSessionState.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:557)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain.runHive(HiveMain.java:336)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain.run(HiveMain.java:313)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:58)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain.main(HiveMain.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:242)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
```

As per my best knowledge it seems that the field which is needed for the job, is not defined in any configuration file of hive, tez or hive2. But at the same type there is no such property as hive.tez.hs2.user.access to configure hive, tez or hive2 configuration xmls.
I tried to add following lines to the sql.hql script:

```
set hive.execution.engine=tez; 
set hive.tez.hs2.user.access=true;
```

as well as property to hive-site.xml cond file.

```
<property>
  <name>hive.tez.hs2.user.access</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Of course without effect.
The only page i've found about this field is: 
https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf.ConfVars.html#HIVETEZHS2USERACCESS

but doesn't really know how i can use this variable in configuration/hql file.
Appreciate any help.